# Test class passed, but main class only 44%

Tags: unit-test, class, apex-email-service, apex

Good Morning Salesforce Stackexchange

I have the following test class called “DeactivateUsers_Test” which has passed however main class “DeactivateUsers” is only getting code coverage of 44% (48/108)

```
@isTest

private class DeactivateUsers_Test {
    static testMethod void testuserdeactivate() {
        String mydomain = 'Hotmail.com';
        List<User> tobeadded = new List<User>();
        //enter the profile name below that you want to set for the test users.
        Profile prof = [select id from profile where name='NL: Sales & Marketing User'];
        //make sure to add/remove the fields below that are required at your company to create new users

        //create test user 3
        User u3 = new User();
        u3.email = 'u3user@' + mydomain;
        u3.lastname = 'tester';
        u3.firstname = 'u3user';
        u3.emailencodingkey='UTF-8';
        u3.alias = 'u3user';
        u3.languagelocalekey='en_US';  
        u3.localesidkey='en_US';
        u3.timezonesidkey='America/Los_Angeles';
        u3.profileid = prof.Id;
        u3.isactive = False;
        u3.Inactive_Date__c = null;
        u3.username='u3user@' + mydomain;

        //add test user to the tobeupdated list
        tobeadded.add(u3);

        //create user 4
        User u4 = new User();
        u4.email = 'u4user@' + mydomain;
        u4.lastname = 'tester';
        u4.firstname = 'u4user';
        u4.emailencodingkey='UTF-8';
        u4.alias = 'u4user';
        u4.languagelocalekey='en_US';  
        u4.localesidkey='en_US';
        u4.timezonesidkey='America/Los_Angeles';
        u4.profileid = prof.Id;
        u4.isactive = False;
        u4.Inactive_Date__c = null;
        u4.username='u4user@' + mydomain;

        //add test user to the tobeupdated list
        tobeadded.add(u4);

        //insert the list of new users
        insert tobeadded;

        //verify the users were inserted
        List<User> insertedlist = [select Id,Email,isactive from User Where CreatedDate = Today];
        System.debug('list includes: ' + insertedlist);
        System.assertNotEquals(insertedlist,null); 

        //test the class again since the users should have been updated and will not match the query this time.
        Test.startTest();
        DeactivateUsers sh2 = new DeactivateUsers();
        String sch2 = '0 0 23 * * ?';
        System.schedule('Test DeactivateUsers data', sch2, sh2);
        Test.stopTest();
    } 
}
```

Class :

```
global class DeactivateUsers implements Schedulable
{    
    Public static void SendLoginEmail(String bucket, String[] adminemail, List<User> ulist){   
        String timeleft = '';
        if(bucket == '1'){
            timeleft = ' 30 days ';
        }
        else{
            timeleft = ' 7 days ';
        }

        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> theEmails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();    

        for(Integer i=0;i<ulist.size();i++){
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                mail.setUseSignature(false);
                mail.setSenderDisplayName('Global CRM Team');
                mail.setTargetObjectId(ulist[i].Id);
                mail.saveAsActivity = false;
                mail.setCcAddresses(adminemail);
                mail.setSubject('Your Salesforce account is scheduled for de-activation');
                mail.setHtmlBody('<p>Dear ' + ulist[i].Name + ',</p><p> You have ' + timeleft + 'to login to your Salesforce account.  If you do not login within the next' + timeleft + 'your account will be deactivated. </p><p> Regards,</p> <p>Global CRM Team</p>');
                theEmails.add(mail);
        }

        if(theEmails.size()>0){ 
            Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail( theEmails );
        }
    }

    global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx)
    {
         // to run the job only in production.  Amended by Daniel Mason on 22/04/2014
        if (UserInfo.getOrganizationId() == '00DR0000001tVYyMAM')                         
        {
            system.debug('*****orgid*****'+UserInfo.getOrganizationId());
            Date myDate = Date.Today();
            String sDate = String.valueOf(myDate);

            //describe the User_Region__c field to get the picklist values
            Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = User.User_Region__c.getDescribe();

            //put the describe results into a list
            List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();

            //create a list to hold the regions that you want to include in the query
            List<String> myregions = new List<String>();

            //this is where you add the values to your myregions list
            for (Schema.PicklistEntry a : ple ) {
                if(a.getValue().contains('Asia') || a.getValue().contains('Japan')){
                    //do not add to search list
                }
                else{
                    //add to the search list
                    myregions.add(a.getValue());
                }
            }

            //hold the users to deactivate
            List<User> updUsers = new List<User>(); 
            String Usr = '';
            String Usr1 = '';
            String Usr2 = '';

            String[] AdminEmail = new String[]{};
            AdminEmail.add('daniel.Mason@Hotmail.com');

            String[] DeveloperEmail = new String[]{};
            DeveloperEmail.add('daniel.Mason@Hotmail.com');

            String eMailSub = '';
            String eMailbdy = '';

           List<User> UserList = new List<User>(); 
           //hold the users at 90 days
           List<User> Bucket1 = new List<User>();
           //hold the users at 113 days
           List<User> Bucket2 = new List<User>();

            if(Test.isRunningTest()) 
            {
                // To increase the code coverage during running the test class
                UserList = [
                    SELECT Id, Name,isactive,lastlogindate,createddate,Inactive_Date__c
                    FROM User
                    WHERE 
                    isactive = False and Inactive_Date__c= null
                     LIMIT 2];
            }
            else
            {                      
                UserList = [ SELECT Id, Name,isactive,lastlogindate,createddate, Inactive_Date__c
                    FROM User
                    WHERE isactive = True
                    AND User_Region__c =: myregions
                    AND Management_User__c = False
                    AND Management_User__c = false
                    AND Eloqua_User__c = false
                    AND Function__c = null
                    and Local_Administrator__c Not In ('IT Support, System or Integration','Training or Test')
                    ];  
            }

            Integer i =1;
            Integer j =1;
            Integer k =1;
            for(user u: UserList)
            {
                 integer Days;
                 if(u.lastlogindate == null){
                    Days = Integer.valueOf((System.Now().getTime() - u.CreatedDate.getTime())/(1000*60*60*24));
                 }else{
                    Days = Integer.valueOf((System.Now().getTime() - u.lastlogindate.getTime())/(1000*60*60*24));
                 } 
                 if(Test.isRunningTest()){
                    if(Days == 0){
                    Usr1 = Usr1 + j+'. '+u.name +  '<br/>';
                    j = j+1; 
                    Bucket1.add(u);

                    Usr2 = Usr2 + k+'. '+u.name +  '<br/>';
                    k = k+1; 
                    Bucket2.add(u);

                     Usr = Usr + i+'. '+u.name +  '<br/>';
                    i = i+1; 
                    u.isActive = False;
                    u.Inactive_Date__c = System.Today();
                    updUsers.add(u);

                    }
                 }
                 else{

                     if(Days == 90){
                        Usr1 = Usr1 + j+'. '+u.name +  '<br/>';
                        j = j+1; 
                        Bucket1.add(u);
                     }
                     else if(Days == 113){
                        Usr2 = Usr2 + k+'. '+u.name +  '<br/>';
                        k = k+1; 
                        Bucket2.add(u);
                     }
                     else if(Days >=120){
                         Usr = Usr + i+'. '+u.name +  '<br/>';
                        i = i+1; 
                        u.isActive = False;
                        u.Inactive_Date__c = System.Today();
                        updUsers.add(u);
                     } 
                     else{
                        //do nothing
                     } 
              }
          }

          //process the 30 days to deactivation  emails
            if(Bucket1.size()>0)
            {
                try
                {
                    SendLoginEmail('1',AdminEmail, Bucket1);                 
                    sndEmail(AdminEmail,'30 Day notice sent List for '+sDate,'Dear Administrator,<br/><br/>The following Org users have been sent the 30 day deactivation notice during todayís run.<br/><br/>'+Usr1);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    system.debug('Exception:'+e);
                    sndEmail(AdminEmail,'Exception in 30 Day notice emails '+sDate,'Dear Administrator,<br/><br/><font color="red">The following exception has stopped todays 30 day deactivation notice during todayís Run.<br/><br/>'+e+'<br/><br/></font> The below users will have to be manually emailed.<br/><br/>'+Usr1);
                }
           }
           else
           {
                sndEmail(DeveloperEmail,'No 30 day notice emails  '+sDate,'Dear Administrator,<br/><br/>There are no 30 day notices sent today');
           }

         //process the 1 week to deactivation  emails
         if(Bucket2.size()>0)
           {
                try
                {
                    SendLoginEmail('2', AdminEmail,Bucket2);                  
                    sndEmail(AdminEmail,'1 week notice sent List for '+sDate,'Dear Administrator,<br/><br/>The following org users have been sent the 1 week deactivation notice during todayís run.<br/><br/>'+Usr2);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    system.debug('Exception:'+e);
                    sndEmail(AdminEmail,'Exception in 1 week notice emails '+sDate,'Dear Administrator,<br/><br/><font color="red">The following exception has stopped todays 1 week deactivation notice during todayís Run.<br/><br/>'+e+'<br/><br/></font> The below users will have to be manually emailed.<br/><br/>'+Usr2);
                }
           }
           else
           {
            sndEmail(DeveloperEmail,'No 1 week notice emails  '+sDate,'Dear Administrator,<br/><br/>There are no 1 week notices sent today');
           }

            //process the user deactivation
           if(updUsers.size()>0)
           {
                try
                {
                    system.debug('Try Part  --- UpdUsersListSize--'+updUsers.size());   
                    update updUsers;
                    system.debug('Try Part after update');   
                    sndEmail(AdminEmail,'Deactivated User List for '+sDate,'Dear Administrator,<br/><br/>The following org users have been deactivated during todayís run.<br/><br/>'+Usr);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    system.debug('Exception:'+e);
                    sndEmail(AdminEmail,'Exception in Deactivate Users '+sDate,'Dear Administrator,<br/><br/><font color="red">The following exception has stopped todays Deactivate Users Run.<br/><br/>'+e+'<br/><br/></font> The below users will have to be manually deactivated.<br/><br/>'+Usr);
                }
           }
           else
           {
            sndEmail(DeveloperEmail,'No Deactivated Users '+sDate,'Dear Administrator,<br/><br/>There are no deactived users today');
           }  
      }
    }

    Public void sndEmail(String[] ToAdr,String Sub, String bdy){
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        mail.setUseSignature(false);
        mail.setSenderDisplayName('Global CRM Team');
        mail.setToAddresses(ToAdr);
        mail.setSubject(Sub);
        mail.setHtmlBody(bdy);
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
    }
}
```

Comment: can you highlight which lines are not covered and what's the problem you have covering them?

Comment: @ PepeFloyd in the test i think i need to mention these lines in the DeactivateUsers class

Line, 4,7,9,10,13,16,18,21-28,30,34.36,110,133,139-141,143-145,147-151,157-160,162-165,167-171,183,185,187,190,192,203,205,207,210,212,223,226,228,231,233

Looking at the code its mainly around the email part. Howvever i never referenced emails in a test code, so i dont know where to begin/start

Comment: @user8746 line numbers are really hard to grok in code samples on this site. As PepeFloyd mentioned, it is much easier for us to help you if you can highlight the code that has no coverage. I am not sure what/if the markdown syntax is but you can use inline HTML, a span tag at the very least.

Comment: A small point for future reference. The test class doesn't pass, it's only testing the main class, it isn't testing itself.

Answer (score 3):

A few points:

- You have about 17 decision points in your DeactivateUsers class, but your test class does not really test any of these decisions.
- You're adding data into the DeactivateUsers class itself using a `if(Test.isRunningTest())` statement, but this should be added into your test class.  That's the point of the test class.  It sets up the data that is going to test your logic and that's where you get your code coverage from.

The point of the test class is to create the various conditions that will test the various decisions in your code.  You should have at least as many test methods in your test class as you have decisions in your code.